# Opencart. Как заполнить поле "Город" в информации о клиенте

Tags: php, javascript, opencart

На сайте стоит модуль simplecheckout, при оформлении заказа он просит ввести адрес, все работает нормально. Мне нужно достать из этого адреса город и при добавлении адреса заполнять поле "Город" в информации о клиенте в админке, а не только "Адрес". Достать город не проблема, но я не знаю каким образом мне этот полученный город поместить в поле "Город" в админке. В коде ниже кусок кода, который срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку "Добавить адрес".

```
var addressValue = document.querySelector(".new-address").value;
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/simplecheckout_shipping_address/addAddress',
                            type: 'post',
                            data: {new_address: addressValue},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(json) {
                                $('select[id=\'shipping_address_address_id\']').val(json);
                                $('select[id=\'shipping_address_address_id\']').trigger('change');
                                if(typeof (json) == 'number'){
                                    $.magnificPopup.close();
                                    reloadAll();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно заполнить скрытое поле #shipping_address_city